# Ao executar comando "java" no CMD não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, instalador

Depois de executar o comando `javac` normalmente e criar o arquivo `.class`,
tento executar o comando `java` mais ele da esse problema de não ser possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal.

Creio eu que possa ser uma confusão minha nas variáveis de ambiente pois estou começando agora
a aprender programação e realmente não intendo muito sobre tais variáveis.

De qualquer forma usei esse "passo-a-passo" no link abaixo para configurar as variáveis do sistema:

http://tisuperinfo.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/problema-javac-nao-e-reconhecido-como.html

Utilizei apenas os comandos `javac` e `java` no `cmd`, fora os de se localizar nos diretórios.

Usando esse código abaixo, logo apos o comando java para executar o programa, ocorre.                                   Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal CPrincipal.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CPrincipal {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        JFrame janela = new JFrame ();

        janela.setSize(500,300);
        janela.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar seu código nele, os comandos que você usou e a saída do console?

Comment: Pelo que você falou sobre classe principal acredito que a classe do arquivo .java que você fez tem um método main, sem o método main a aplicação não irá iniciar. 

O main é o ponto de entrada do programa, é por ele que o programa inicia.

Comment: Coloque exatamente a mensagem de erro que ocorreu e em que momento ela ocorreu.

Comment: Acho que o problema é que não defeniu a variavél PATH corretamente.

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta com outra mais ampla e que pode auxiliar mais futuros usuários do site com a mesma dúvida:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82229/erro-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-localizar-nem-carregar-a-classe-principal-em-java-eclipse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No diretorio onde você compilou o arquivo com javac

```
javac CPrincipal.java
```

vai aparecer o arquivo **CPrincipal.class**

Nesse mesmo diretório, escreva

```
java CPrincipal
```

A tela do JFrame deverá aparecer normalmente.

Comment: o problema e justamente esse... eu faço exatamente isso mais  da o erro ao usa o comando java. ERRO: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal CPrincipal.class

Comment: Remove todos os java que você tem instalado e poe 1 SDK apenas. Depois verifique se o %Java_home% esta no environment variables e adiciona o %Java_home%\bin no path. Por fim, quando for chamar o comando java, veja a opção de adicionar classpath e coloque um ponto. Tipo **java -classpath=. CPrincipal**

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente você fez a mesma besteira que eu na hora de criar as variáveis do ambiente.

A variável `ClassPath` precisa ter um `.;` antes do caminho atribuído.

A minha ficou assim:
`.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib`