# Erro: não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal em Java (Eclipse ou CMD)?

Tags: java

Se você em algum momento se deparou com a mensagem de erro: `Erro: não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal` provavelmente não vai conseguir executar seus códigos em Java.

No eclipse eu me deparei com essa mensagem:

`Erro: não é possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal`

Mas, também é possível que algumas pessoas se deparem com essa mensagem no próprio "CMD"? Se sim, como proceder para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Checou se colocou o método de entrada `public static void main(String... args)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, se você se deparar com um erro como esse no Eclipse, provavelmente você importou algum projeto do seu `*workspace*` ou de qualquer outro lugar do seu `Windows` ou você mexeu nas configurações padrões do `Eclipse`.

Se você importou um projeto, verifique na pasta (abra através do `explorer`) e perceba que tem um arquivo com o nome `.classpath`, abra o arquivo com um editor (`Notepad`, por exemplo). Note que vai existir uma variável como essa:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
```

Possivelmente se você trocou de versão do `Eclipse`, essa variável poderá mudar, causando a mensagem de erro citada por não encontrar o JRE "padrão" do `Eclipse`. Esse erro pode ser corrigido criando um novo projeto Java no próprio Eclipse, e após isso importar o seu projeto desmarcando os arquivos `.project` e `.classpath`.

Se você encontrou esse problema ao tentar compilar um código manualmente através do `prompt de comandos do Windows (CMD)` é provável que as variáveis de ambiente estejam mal configuradas e o JDK (Java Development Kit) ou o JRE (Java Runtime) estejam incorretas.

Neste caso, verifique se você criou uma variável do tipo JAVA_HOME, e em seguida definiu como valor da mesma o caminho do seu `JDK`, no meu caso a pasta padrão do `JDK` é:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20

Essa variável serve como as variáveis de linguagens de programação que utilizamos, a JAVA_HOME armazenará o caminho padrão do meu pacote de compilação da linguagem JAVA.

Após isso, verifique se na variável de ambiente `CLASSPATH` possui o valor:

> .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar

Esta claro que o sistema operacional irá trocar o valor da variável `JAVA_HOME` pelo caminho do seu `JDK` padrão dentro do `Windows`, ou seja, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`.

Outra observação importante é que, caso você compile seu código via `CMD`, lembre-se sempre de compilar na ordem correta as classes, ou seja se a `ClasseA` instancia a `ClasseB`, a `ClasseB` deve ser compilada primeiro, e a `ClasseA` em seguida.

Desta forma, também é importante verificar se você está utilizando `package` (pastas), pois se não indicar o caminho de compilação dos arquivos no comando, o seu arquivo de `bitecodes` (arquivos com extensão `.class`) padrão ficará dentro da própria pasta que está se compilando o código. Assim, se você for compilar a `ClasseA` que pertence ao `pacote A`, e a mesma utiliza a `ClasseB` que pertence ao `pacote B`, você deve possuir essa estrutura de pastas, compilar a `ClasseB` dentro de um `pacote B` (colocar o arquivo `ClasseB.class` dentro da pasta `pacote B`), em seguida compilar a `ClasseA` dentro de um `pacote A` (colocar o arquivo `ClasseA.class` dentro da pasta `pacote A`). Nesse caso a `ClasseA` é a principal, então  você executa o arquivo de `bitecode` a partir dela (`$ java ClasseA`)

Caso não faça isso, o compilador não irá conseguir enxergar as outras pastas, ocasionando erros do tipo "Não foi possível encontrar a classe XXXXX".

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` está _deprecated_.

Answer (score 3):

Este erro também ocorre quando você executa seu programa no CMD com a extensão .java.

```
c:\>java Exemplo.java
Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal Exemplo.java
```

Basta executar o programa sem a extensão.

```
c:\>java Exemplo
Resultado com sucesso
```

Answer (score 2):

Se Estive utilizando linha de comando para compilar usar: `javac -cp /caminho/prodiretorio/src package.NomeDaClasse`

Executar:

```
java -cp /caminho/prodiretorio/src package.NomeDaClasse
```

Lembrando que classes dependentes devem ser compiladas primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

#### Navegue até o diretório onde estão os seus arquivos `.class`:

```
cd C:\Users\MeuNome\workspace\ProjetoX\bin\br\com\pacote
```

#### Execute o codigo abaixo passando o classpath como referência:

```
java -classpath ../../.. br.com.pacote.ClassePrincipal
```

#### Se não funcionar com o caminho relativo tente com o caminho absoluto:

```
java -classpath C:/Users/MeuNome/workspace/ProjetoX/bin/ br.com.pacote.ClassePrincipal
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com o mesmo problema, resolvi removendo a variável de ambiente **classpath**.
No meu caso(Linux) ela apontava para "/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_261/lib", pelo que eu entendi ao tentar rodar a minha classe o Java estava procurando no caminho indicado pelo classpath.

Comment: No caso não devia remover, e sim trocar por `".:/usr(...)"` onde `.` indica o diretório local (lembrando que no caso do Windows em vez de separar com `:` é com `;`).

Comment: Não precisava remover. Bastava apenas `Editar` a referida variável de ambiente.

Answer (score -1):

Muito simples de resolver esse problema, claro se você instalou corretamente o java. Bom só é você tira : (package xxxxxxx;) da classe e compilar no CMD normalmente com o : 1° (javac Nome_Classe.java) 2° (java Nome_Classe).
Ele executará normalmente.

Comment: Aqui funcionou! vlw!

Answer (score -3):

Tenta colocar o nome da classe certo, estava tentando colocar o nome da classe tudo minusculo, ai quando coloquei exatamente como estava escrito deu certo...não coloquei javac ... apenas java e o nome da classe exatamente como esta escrito.