# Como rodar JADE (Java Agent DEvelopment Framework) no linux?

Tags: java, linux, jade

Como rodar JADE [(Java Agent DEvelopment Framework)](http://jade.tilab.com/), é um Framework para SMA, na ultima versão do lubuntu ?

*Estou usando Lubuntu 32bits - 17.10.1.*

Estou tendo um problemas em rodar ela no lubuntu (o pc que eu tenho disponível para uso em casa no momento está péssimo para rodar windows, ai to tendo que me virar com lubuntu).

O que fiz até agora:

1. Baixei no site a lib extrai o .jar.
2. No terminal digitei `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`
3. No fim do arquivo aberto digitei `export CLASSPATH=/home/user/Desktop/JADE/jade-core/jade/lib/jade.jar:/home/Desktop/` que é onde eu extrai a lib. O caminho está exatamente igual, sem erros.
4. No terminal novamente: `java jade.Boot -gui`. Recebo o seguinte erro

> "Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal jade.Boot"

Como resolver isso?

Estou usando

```
$ java -version
```

> java version "1.8.0_171"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: ja configurou as variaveis de ambiente,  tem esse post aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82229/erro-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel-localizar-nem-carregar-a-classe-principal-em-java-eclipse

Comment: O post é para windows, né, meu problema é linux.